# Mock Class.class in Java JUnit 5

Tags: java, junit5

I am trying to test a overridden method that takes in a parameter of type `Class<? extends HttpMessageConverter<?>>` as an input. As this parameter is not being used in my implementation, I want to mock it (or in worst case I can go ahead with actual initialization of the instance).

```
@Mock
Class<? extends HttpMessageConverter<?>> selectedConverterType;
```

This is how I am mocking it (although I have tried using `Mockito.mock()`, but even that did not work)

```
@Override
    public Object beforeBodyWrite(Object body, MethodParameter returnType, MediaType selectedContentType,
            Class<? extends HttpMessageConverter<?>> selectedConverterType, ServerHttpRequest request,
            ServerHttpResponse response) {.....}
```

This is the method I am trying to test.

Some observation :
It fails when `MockCreationValidator` try to validate the type of mock in `MockSettingsImpl`. This happens only for `Class` type, other objects are being mocked as expected.

Answer (score 0):

As the concerned instance is not being used in implementation, passing it as `null` did the job for me. It is not a good idea to do so, but I am running out of time and I want to reach code coverage limit.